# How to "tie" one HTML element's position to another HTML element's position?

Tags: html, css

I've run into quite complicated HTML problem. I'm making a website and when users click menu, the menu popup slides out.

The problem that I'm having is how do I make sure that popup slider is always below the menu link.

As I resize page the menu link moves around and it's position is not predefined.

It could be at {x;y}={1000; 200} but if I resize the page smaller, it can move to {x,y}={400; 300}.

I tried setting `position` to `absolute` for menu and positioning it at `1000, 250` (below link), but it doesn't work if I resize the page smaller as the link is now at 400; 300 and not at 1000; 200...

Therefore my question - how do I "tie" the menu slider to menu link, so that no matter where the menu link is, it was always below it?

I'd like to do this in pure CSS and HTML with no JavaScript function calls.

Comment: Can you give some kind of an example with code or a live site? Your wording of 'popup sliders' and 'menu links' doesn't really paint a very clear mental image.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to do that is to make it like this:

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="menuOpener>Menu</div>
  <div id="menuItems">Items</div>
</div>
```

And then

```css
#wrapper { position: relative; } 
#menuItems { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; }
```

Like that, the menu items are positioned absolutely but relative to the wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, try the following:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    repositionPopupSlider();
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I'd like to avoid JavaScript function call on every resize.